# How to generate regex for sttring with undefined length

Tags: regex

I want to generate a regular expression for following scenario:

- String can contain alphanumeric characters
- string having undefined
- After two characters there is '-'
- The string will be in the following format -
        XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX (e.g. 00-13-50-FF-FE-11-D8-3A)

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: using quantifiers `*` or `+` gives always pattern to match undefined length, maybe just `^[A-Za-z0-9]{2}(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]{2})*$`

Comment: With undefined, do you mean [`^(?:(?:[A-Za-z\d]{2}-){7}+[A-Za-z\d]{2}|undefined)$`](https://regex101.com/r/k9yLM3/1) or 
[`(?:(?:[A-Za-z\d]{2}-){7}+[A-Za-z\d]{2}|undefined)`](https://regex101.com/r/k9yLM3/2)?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with:

```
\b([A-Za-z0-9]{2}-)+[A-Za-z0-9]{2}\b
```

This command is searching for a sequence like `XX-` repeated multiple times which is then followed by closing `XX`, surrounded by word boundaries `\b`.

This may appear more conventionally in vim as:

```
\<\([A-Za-z0-9]\{2\}-\)\+[A-Za-z0-9]\{2\}\>
```

Where brackets are escaped so they are not included in the search term. If you are sure there are no underscores that will cause false positives you can simplify to:

```
\b(\w{2}-)+\w{2}\b
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your reply
Its working for XX for 7 times but my string is length is not predefined. It may vary.

Comment: Instead of `{7}` you could use `+` which will match any number of repeated sequences. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: If this works for you then please accept it as the answer, it benefits others who visit this question in future.